# How do I move the "details pane" to the bottom of "File Explorer" in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In windows 7/8 the details pane showed up in the bottom of "File Explorer". In windows 10 it shows to the right and you can't have "Preview Pane" and "Details Pane" simultaneously enabled since they both use the right portion of "File Explorer".

How can I move the "Details Pane" to the bottom of "File Explorer" like it was in Windows 8 on Windows 10 without using Third Party Tools.

[image: Details on Right]

[image: Details on Bottom]

Comment: Windows 8 & 10 depreciated this feature and is no longer natively supported as far as I know

Comment: Probably an "Update"..... @JW0914

Answer (score 4):

According to an [Insider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUrLw.png) on [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-can-i-move-the-details-pane-to-the-bottom-of/2c3da95c-a2b3-4814-9448-953da946fd57) thread it is not possible anymore without 3rd party software, like [BrainStorm.exe](https://superuser.com/users/407846/brainstorm-exe) suggested.

You can download "[OldNewExplorer](https://msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-118/)" and when installing check "Show details pane on the bottom". Due to an issue you may have to enable "Launch folder windows in a separate process" inside `Folder Options > View`. Full credit to BrainStorm.exe for [suggesting](https://superuser.com/a/1134638/737975) it.

*However*, you can add extra details with a reg hack, as suggested [here](https://winaero.com/blog/customize-details-pane-windows-10/). You can download the reg hack [here](https://winaero.com/request.php?1865).

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Unfortunately I can't get this to work on build 1809 so I guess it does not work on newer builds.

Edit: Nice I can embed pictures now.

Comment: I'm guessing your rep is to low to post images? Otherwise I'd say put them directly in the post. Otherwise best answer possible really, a confirmation that it is NOT possible... :(

Comment: Please use official links for software [OldNewExplorer], linking to the actual site and not a compressed file, as there's no way for a potential user to verify that download is legit... plus it lacks HTTPS, and software should not be downloaded from non-HTTPS addresses.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers yes it is unfortunately.

Comment: @JW0914 the only mirror I could find via Google is that one. HowToGeek and MSDN both point to it. Sorry

Comment: @ChristoferMinestar Then a link shouldn't be posted since StackExchange sites are answer sites. _Its an extremely bad idea to link to untrusted executable files_, and specifically to the OldNewExplorer link, its about as insecure & untrusted as one can possibly get: **(1)** _It's not an official site,  **(2)** _there's no SHA256 hash from the developer or GPG signature_, **(3)** _It's non-HTTPS, therefore the file cannot be trusted and allows for a MITM attack_. **_The developer is [MSFN developer tihiy](https://msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-118/?do=findComment&comment=1060900)_**

Comment: @ChristoferMinestar I've edited the OldNewExplorer link in your answer to point to the developer's OldNewExplorer thread, of which has an HTTPS link for downloading.

Comment: @JW0914 thanks. I'll make sure to get a proper source next time.

Answer (score 3):

Using some info obtained from [this page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/how-to-move-details-pane-to-bottom-of-window-10/6d885636-288a-4841-87a1-c1c99a2462df), I discovered that you can. First, you will need to download the free tool [OldNewExplorer](https://msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-118/), run it, check the box that says "Show details pane on the bottom", and click Install. It should be on the bottom of your explorer windows now.

There is an issue that can occur that can cause explorer to seem to ignore the settings you have set in OldNewExplorer. You can work around this going to Folder Options->View and check the box "Launch folder windows in a separate  process".  This will have windows open explorer windows in a different process than the one that is running your task bar.

Comment: I edited your question to ask for an answer without Third Party Tools, I also was able to get this to work with "OldNewExplorer" but I worry what issues it will cause down the line. Hope you don't mind! This answer does still work as of Win10 v 1809, but again, I'd prefer a Reg Hack.

Comment: If I don't get an answer, you'll probably get the bounty!

Comment: Please use official links for software [OldNewExplorer], linking to the actual site and not a compressed file, as there's no way for a potential user to verify that download is legit... plus it lacks HTTPS, and software should not be downloaded from non-HTTPS addresses.

Comment: @BrainStorm.exe I've edited the OldNewExplorer link in your answer to point to the developer's OldNewExplorer thread, of which has an HTTPS link for downloading.